# Rescale x-Axis in surf plot

Tags: matlab, axis, surf

I have a 1024 by 100 matrix. When I use the function surf it plots the data with axis limit 0 to 1024 for x, 0 to 100 for y and the entries of the matrix as z values (as expected). 
Now I want to keep everything in the plot the same, except for the x axis limits: I want to have them from 400 to 1000 i.e. I want to rescale the x axis. I don't want to start at the 400th entry and stop at the 1000th. I want to have the first entry to correstpond to 400 and the last one to 1000th. In other words change only the labels of the x axis to go from 400 to 1000 and not from 0 to 1024. Is there a simple way to do that or do I need to use meshgrid?

Comment: Can you try to shorten all that to a sentence and an image? You can set the axes properties easily and use the function `axes` for limits. what of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: When I use axis([Xmin Xmax Ymin Ymax Zmin Zmax]) it plots only the entries between these limits. I just want to change my x axis to have 400 as beginning and 1000 as max value.

Comment: Can you describe the difference between "only show this values" and "not show the other values"? I am not sure if I get it. Do you want to change the `xlabel` and `xtick`?

Comment: The numbers on my x axis should not be going from 0 to 1024 but from 400 to 1000. I could do it in paint but I am looking for a more adequate way to do it.

Comment: I can't upload an image for some reason. I get "Failed to upload image; an error occured at imgur".

Comment: I am not sure about the quote. Which part of the post does it refer to? I can't find it.

Comment: So you want the data to be from  0 to 1024, but the axis labels only to label part of it? Or you want only the data from 400 to 1000 be shown? Its not very clear what you need

Comment: I want all the data. X values should go from 400 to 1000 i.e. first value in the plot should have the label 400 instead of 0 and the last one should have 1000 instead of 1024.

Comment: I hope this link works: https://ibb.co/dRwDQe
I want the plot to stay exactly as it is, just change the x axis labels

Comment: So, coming back to my first comment: What is your problem with changing axis proerties? a quick google to "change x labels matlab" gives [a nice tutorial](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html). Why does that not work?

Comment: I tried using different Xticks but I end up with the ticks between the 400th and 1000th entry only. So from 0 to 400 I have no x axis labels and then I have them up to 1000. That's not what I want. I want to replace the x labels and keep everything the way it is. Can I do this with Tick values (and not manually for every single one)?

Comment: Yes, read the tutorial. You want to chagne `xticklabels` but not `xticks`

Comment: I get an error "Undefined function 'xticks' for input arguments of type 'double'." Probably because it's a surf plot and not a normal 2d plot?

Comment: Read the link. If you do not want to, then you will not get the answer. Good luck.

Comment: The link doesn't really help as I get an error when I try to do what the article says. It would probably work for a 2d plot but not for my case.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. obchardon answered the question allready. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
%Example data
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.1:8,1:0.1:8);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);
%Example plot
surf(X,Y,Z)

%We change the XTick Labels
xt = get(gca,'XTick'); %get the actual xtick value
xl = arrayfun(@num2str, linspace(400,1000,length(xt)), 'Uniform', false).';
set(gca,'XTickLabel',xl) %set the news xtick labels.
```

With `set(gca,'XTickLabel',your_cell_of_string)` you can change the actual XTickLabel with some news string, `xl` and `xt` must have the same size.

Comment: @Rosen: changing the `XTickLabels` is not necessary if you pass the right `X` and `Y` arrays to `surf`. Read the docs to `surf`.

Comment: It's just how I get my data. I have 1024 pixels on a detector and from the first to the last I get light with wavelength between 400 and 1000 nm. So after 100 measurements I get one big 1000X1024 matrix in the format the detector gives it. Then I just use surf(matrix) without defining X, Y mesh. Can you link the docs describing how to do it directly - without making X,Y arrays?